# C# IndexOutOfRangeException on CSV-File

Tags: c#, csv, linq-to-xml, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to read a CSV-File and write an XML-File out of it. The basic idea how the csv lines are splitted I understand. But my Code gives me an exception, I don't understand.

First the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Insert Filename please");
       string path = Console.ReadLine();

           string[] source = File.ReadAllLines(path);
           XElement output = new XElement("Consumer",
               from str in source
               let fields = str.Split(',')
               select new XElement("consumer",
                   new XElement(fields[0],
                   new XAttribute(fields[1], fields[2]),
                   new XAttribute(fields[3], fields[4])
                   )));

                Console.WriteLine(output);
                Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

}
So thats the Code and when I debug it, I get a failure message that says its an "OutOfRangeException". I know what this kind of exception means, but I just cannot find a solution for it. I interpreted every character between a comma as a field. So normally the Array shouldn't be bigger than the amount of fields in the CSV-File. Why I get OutOfBounds now, is mysterious for me.

Thank you very much for reading and helping :)

Edit: My CSV-File that I used was corrupted, so that I didnt get anything useful. I fixed and the codes works, but just as long as the CSV dont contain an empty field. The exception that pops up sais, that "A Name cannot start with the Charakter ' ', hexadezimal value 0x20. I dont know how to handle this Problem. I tried using the FastCSVReader library of Lumenworks, but didnt get an solution.

Comment: Does all strings in `source` contains 36 `,` characters (including the very last line)?

Comment: Check the count of `fields` array. Does it have 37 or more elements?

Comment: It would be great to see the source file

Comment: check there is not a blank line at the bottom of the file as this has caused me problems in the past

Comment: For further information. The source file is a CSV-File with words and numbers written in first column of each line separated by commas.

For example like this:

GREAL,Great Lakes Food Market,Howard Snyder,Marketing Manager, (503) 555-7555,2732 Baker Blvd.,Eugene,OR,97403,USA, 12 Orchestra Terrace,Walla Walla,WA,99362,USA, Lazy K Kountry Store,John Steel,Marketing Manager,

Now I found a slghtly difference in my file. The values are separated with ", ", a comma followed by a blank. Does this make any difference??

Comment: the comment dont show i exactly, but the values are in several lines and the source file got more than 37 elements, I dont use every element in the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be at least one line with less than 37 fields. Perhaps there's a blank line at the end?

You could try checking `fields.Length` before proceeding, i.e.:

```
XElement toXML = new XElement("Root",
from str in source
let fields = str.Split(',')
where fields.Length >= 37 // <==== Check #fields
select new XElement("Consumer",
            new XAttribute("name", fields[0]),
        new XElement(fields[3]),
            new XAttribute(fields[4], fields[5]),
            new XAttribute(fields[6], fields[7]),
            new XAttribute(fields[8], fields[9]),
            new XAttribute(fields[10], fields[11]),
            new XAttribute(fields[12], fields[13]),
            new XAttribute(fields[14], fields[15]),
            new XAttribute(fields[16], fields[17]),
            new XAttribute(fields[18], fields[19]),
            new XAttribute(fields[20], fields[21]),
        new XElement(fields[22]),
              new XAttribute(fields[24], fields[25]),
              new XAttribute(fields[26], fields[27]),
              new XAttribute(fields[28], fields[29]),
        new XElement(fields[30]),
              new XAttribute(fields[32], ""),
              new XAttribute(fields[33], fields[34]),
              new XAttribute(fields[35], fields[36])));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I changed my code according to your suggestion. Now the exception don't occur anymore. Thank you for that, but the Output is just <root/>.

Comment: @Alika87 I suspect the format of your file isn't really correct. Can you paste the entire file into your question?

Comment: In the comment under my question i posted a example how my file looks like.